# Restoring TFS 2015 databases to TFS 2018 failed using TFS Scheduled Backup/Restore

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2016

I am performing a migration based upgrade from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018. I used TFS (Scheduled Backups) to perform the full backup, but when I tried to restore using the TFS 2018 scheduled backup it would not list the database. If I clicked "List Backups" the "wait dialog" would spin once and die. I have nothing in the log files. The directory where the databases reside are shared correctly with permissions and appear as a share in explorer. I am using Windows Server 2016. I had to perform the restore using SSMS 17.6 for SQL Server 2016. This made me nervous since the protection that the per-prod upgrade performs on the databases are not performed. Has anyone seen this issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the ServerID by running the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\TfsConfig.exe" ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:[New Sql server name] /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the built-in backup/restore tool is for DR scenarios, not for migration or upgrade scenarios. I would not expect it to work in the fashion you're trying to use it.

Your best bet is to manually restore the databases, then perform a test upgrade.

Comment: I thought the purpose of using TFS for backup/restore is because it will strip away GUIDS and pointers so when you perform a pre-production install you do not interfere with production environment. Could you elaborate on why it is used for DR and not my situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the scheduled backups wizard to generate database backups from your production deployment, you can also use it to restore backups on your pre-production deployment. If not, you can of course follow standard SQL procedures to restore backups as well.

You could try a dry run of the upgrade by following the article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2018
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Restore Database manually in SQL and then install TFS 2018. Select Development type as **'I have existing databases to use for Team Foundation Server development'**. It will list down 2015 database. You can run the wizard and upgrade it.

Comment: Ok, the problem I get, is it's looking to connect to the old server. The old server died, so how do I do this with out the old server and just the back up files and encryption key?